# Access to simple report filters and input controls via BusinessObjects Java SDK

Tags: java, business-objects

How can I get access to BusinessObjects simple report filters and input controls via Java SDK? I've searched in DocumentInstance class, but all I've found is query filters. I've missed something or there are no solution?

Comment: Which version of BusinessObjects are you using ?

Comment: Business Object Enterprise XI 3.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Input Controls are not exposed in the Java SDK for BusinessObjects XI 3.x. For managing Input Controls, you need to have at least BusinessObjects 4.1 SP6 and use the new RESTfull SDK.

You can obtain report filters with the following code:

```
DocumentInstance documentInstance = null;  // I let you handle openDocument
ReportStructure structure = documentInstance.getStructure();
ReportContainer firstReport = (ReportContainer) structure.getReportElement(0);
if (firstReport.hasFilter()) {
    FilterContainer filterContainer = firstReport.getFilter();
    // Now you have the filters tree
}
```

Here is the code to retrieve the filter bar filters:

```
Reports reports = document.getReports();
Report report = reports.getItem(0);
// Gets the drill info
DrillInfo drillInfo = (DrillInfo) report.getNamedInterface("DrillInfo");
DrillBar drillBar = null;
try {
     drillBar = drillInfo.getDrillBar();
} catch (Exception e) {
    // it may fails if you have prompt to answer for example.
}
if (drillBar != null) {
    // drillBar.getCount();  // to have the number of filters
    DrillBarObject drillBarObject = drillBar.getItem(0);
    System.out.println(drillBarObject.getName()); // Print the filter abject name

    // Print the filter value / if it is an empty string, it means "AllValues"
    System.out.println(drillBarObject.getFilter()); 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I've tried your code, but `hasFilter()` return false. We are talking about the same thing? The report filters from your code example is [simple report filters](https://answers.uchicago.edu/images/group68/16772/Report_Filter_3.jpg)?

Comment: No, we don't talk about the same thing. I give you the code to find filters applied on any blocks and report. You are looking for the filter bar ones.

Comment: Is there the any possibility to get filters from filter bar?

Comment: Yes, I have updated my answer. I hope it works; I haven't work on this release for years :)

Comment: Thank you! I've struggled with this question all week. ^.^

Comment: And yes, the old SDK can be difficult to use. Especially for filters since there are too many types. Hopefully, we have addressed this complexity in latest releases.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't have enough reputation on StackOverflow to upvote your answer :(